# Line breaks and horizontal scrolling in html/css

Tags: html, css

I have a div with many small spans in it. I'd like to have a horizontal scroll bar where the line extends until the line break tags (a-z on each line with a horizontal scroll bar to view the entire line on a narrow screen).

I have added the overflow style to the div and set it to 'auto' but the content is always squeezed into the div and the horizontal scroll bars never show up.

Is it possible to have a collection of spans (or some other tag) followed by a line break to specify when the line ends and where the horizontal scrolling should begin and end?

```
<div style="overflow: auto">
    <span>a</span> <span>b</span> <span>c</span> <span>d</span> <span>e</span>
    <span>f</span> <span>g</span> <span>h</span> <span>i</span> <span>j</span>
    <span>k</span> <span>l</span> <span>m</span> <span>n</span> <span>o</span>
    <span>p</span> <span>q</span> <span>r</span> <span>s</span> <span>t</span>
    <span>u</span> <span>v</span> <span>w</span> <span>x</span> <span>y</span>
    <span>z</span>

    <br>

    <span>a</span> <span>b</span> <span>c</span> <span>d</span> <span>e</span>
    <span>f</span> <span>g</span> <span>h</span> <span>i</span> <span>j</span>
    <span>k</span> <span>l</span> <span>m</span> <span>n</span> <span>o</span>
    <span>p</span> <span>q</span> <span>r</span> <span>s</span> <span>t</span>
    <span>u</span> <span>v</span> <span>w</span> <span>x</span> <span>y</span>
    <span>z</span>

    <br>

    <span>a</span> <span>b</span> <span>c</span> <span>d</span> <span>e</span>
    <span>f</span> <span>g</span> <span>h</span> <span>i</span> <span>j</span>
    <span>k</span> <span>l</span> <span>m</span> <span>n</span> <span>o</span>
    <span>p</span> <span>q</span> <span>r</span> <span>s</span> <span>t</span>
    <span>u</span> <span>v</span> <span>w</span> <span>x</span> <span>y</span>
    <span>z</span>

    <br>

</div>
```

Where is the scroll bar?[image]

Comment: The width of a block level element, the div, will be 100% of the width. That's why there is no scroll bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text inside the div will wrap to fit the div width when necessary. You can prevent this setiing `white-space:nowrap;`. See [white-space](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp).

Here you have an example https://jsfiddle.net/nmagq349/